# Konjunktiv 1 "Ich bräuchte" - verwendbar mit allen Verben?

Tags: conjugation

Ich höre manchmal diese Form:

> Ich bräuchte Ihren Ausweis.

Für mich fühlt es sich an wie eine andere Form von

> Ich würde Ihren Ausweis brauchen.

Aber kann man diese Bildung verallgemeinern für alle Verben? Das heißt, die Bildung *würde + Infinitiv* in jedem Fall durch *Präteritum + Umlaut* ersetzen? Ich wusste dass man es mit den irregulären Verben machen kann, aber gilt es auch für die regulären?

Comment: Das ist kein Konjunktiv 1, sondern 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Du fühlst vollkommen richtig, beides ist – wie @tofro in seinem Kommentar schon sagt – Konjunktiv II. Jedes Verb [citation needed] hat eine Konjunktiv-II-Form, die in einigen Fällen identisch mit *Präteritum + Umlaut* ist:

> ich hätte
>
> ich könnte
>
> ich würde
>
> *aber:* ich ginge

Häufig, insbesondere in der gesprochenen Sprache, »umschreibt« man den Konjunktiv II allerdings mit *werden (Konj. II) + Infinitiv*

> ich würde gehen

Dafür gibt es verschiedene Gründe, die wichtigsten sind m. E.

- dass die Konjunktiv-Form einfach ungewohnt ist und deswegen unnatürlich oder überheblich erscheint, und
- dass der Konjunktiv II in vielen Fällen nicht vom Präteritum zu unterscheiden ist, z. B. bei »arbeiten«, es wird in beiden Fällen zu »ich arbeitete«.